# creating a set of random points on the surface of a sphere

Tags: python, graphics, 3d, space, scatter

i wrote a  code to generate a set of random points on the surface of concentric spheres,where on each sphere I would generate a certain number of points depending on how many concentric sphere surfaces I want as seen in the code written below,you can try to run it and maybe get a better understanding of the issue at hand:

```
class point:
    def __init__(self, x, y, z):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.z = z

    R_list=(0.001 , 0.002, 0.003 , 0.004 ,0.005)
    num_points = 1000/len(R_list)
    LD1 = 0.05
    LD23 = 0.025
    obj_points = []
    condition = True
    for R in R_list:
        while len(rpoints) < num_points:
           theta = np.random.uniform(-math.pi, math.pi)
           phi = np.random.uniform(-math.pi, math.pi)
           pi = R * math.cos(theta) * math.sin(phi) + (LD1 / 2), R * math.sin(theta) * math.sin(phi) + (
                    LD23 / 2), R * math.cos(phi) + (LD23 / 2)
           obj_points.append(point(pi[0], pi[1], pi[2]))
    
      # plott array
    lt = len(obj_points)
    Vis_arr = np.zeros((lt, 3))
    n = 0
    for n in range(0, lt-1 ):
        Vis_arr[n][0] = obj_points[n].x
        Vis_arr[n][1] = obj_points[n].y
        Vis_arr[n][2] = obj_points[n].z
    
    # scattering of points
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
    # scattering of points
    ax.scatter3D(Vis_arr[:, 0], Vis_arr[:, 1], Vis_arr[:, 2], marker="o")
    # graph output fully no evolution
    plt.show()
```

but when I run the code a random point appears out of nowhere:
[image]

I suspect that this is an error in creating the arrays of points but I cant detect the exact reason of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have two errors in your code:

```
while len(rpoints) < num_points:
```

should be:

```
while len(obj_points) < num_points:
```

and

```
for n in range(0, lt-1 ):
```

should be:

```
for n in range(0, lt ):
```

Comment: thanks for your answer it solved the issue.